# Keeping same rest endpoint for complex types in asp.net core api

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, restful-url

I have a Rest endpoint, lets call it tags

http://api/tags

which creates tags objects passing this json format:

```
[{
   "TagName" : "IntegerTag",
   "DataType" : 1,
   "IsRequired" : true
}]
```

If I would like to maintain the same endpoint to create new tags but with  different json format. Lets say I want to create a ListTag

```
[{
   "TagName" : "ListTag",
   "DataType" : 5,
   "Values" : ["Value1", "Value2", "Value3"]
   "IsRequired" : true
}]]
```

or a RangeTag

```
[{
   "TagName" : "RangeTag",
   "DataType" : 6,
   "Min": 1,
   "Max": 10,
   "IsRequired" : true
}]
```

I am not having any problem with C# to create a new Dto on my controller api and pass it as a different parameter because C# admits methods overloads for that:

```
void CreateTags(TagForCreateDto1 dto){…}

void CreateTags(TagForCreateDto2 dto){…}
```

But when I need to maintain in the same controller both methods with a POST request to create the tags, mvc does not allow for the same route to have both.

```
[HttpPost]
void CreateTags(TagForCreateDto1 dto){…}
[HttpPost]
void CreateTags(TagForCreateDto2 dto){…}
```

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following
>   actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied.

Please advise

Comment: You can use a custom JsonConverter for creating the correct classes for you. So, doing some sort of a polymorphic model binding.

Comment: @jpgrassi can you illustrate your approach, because what I am understanding from you is to pass a generic string, that has inside the structure of the jsons and later depending on a discriminator field know how to convert to a specific type, Am I right?

Comment: Something like that. Do you always send those `DataType` fields in your JSON object? Are those 1:1 with the `RangeTag` or `ListTag`? I'm working on an example.. give me some minutes.

Comment: Jsons are different each time you send them but you can pass a different Content-Type to discriminate each request

Comment: What I meant is: do your JSON always have the `DataType` field on them? You need something to be able to identify which kind of model to serialize to.

Comment: If that is your question, yes, they have it

Answer (score 5):

One way to accomplish what you want, having a single `POST endpoint` while being able to post different "versions" of `Tags` is by creating a custom `JsonConverter`.

Basically, since you already have a property `DataType` that can be used to identify which type of `Tag` it is, it's easy to serialize it into the correct type. So, in code it looks like this:

`BaseTag` > `ListTag`, `RangeTag`

```
public class BaseTag
{
    public string TagName { get; set; }

    public int DataType { get; set; }

    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
}

public sealed class ListTag : BaseTag
{
    public ICollection<string> Values { get; set; }
}

public sealed class RangeTag: BaseTag
{
    public int Min { get; set; }

    public int Max { get; set; }
}
```

Then, the custom `PolymorphicTagJsonConverter`

```
public class PolymorphicTagJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) 
        => typeof(BaseTag).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("reader");
        if (serializer == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("serializer");
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;

        var jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

        var target = CreateTag(jObject);
        serializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), target);
        return target;
    }       

    private BaseTag CreateTag(JObject jObject)
    {
        if (jObject == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("jObject");
        if (jObject["DataType"] == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("DataType");

        switch ((int)jObject["DataType"])
        {
            case 5:
                return new ListTag();
            case 6:
                return new RangeTag();
            default:
                return new BaseTag();
        }
    }
}
```

The heavy work is done in `ReadJson` and `Create` methods. `Create` receives an `JObject` and inside it inspects the `DataType` property to figure out which type of `Tag` it is. Then, `ReadJson` just proceeds calling the `Populate` on the `JsonSerializer` for the appropriate `Type`.

You need to tell the framework to use your custom converter then:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(PolymorphicTagJsonConverter))]
public class BaseTag 
{ 
   // the same as before
}
```

Finally, you can just have one `POST` endpoint that will accept all types of tags:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post(ICollection<BaseTag> tags)
{
    return Ok(tags);
}
```

One downside is that `switch` on the converter. You might be okay or not with it.. you could do some smart work and try to make the tag classes implement somehow some interface so you could just call `Create` on the `BaseTag` and it would forward the call to the correct one at runtime, but I guess you can get started with this, and if complexity increases then you can think on a smarter/more automatic way of finding the correct `Tag` classes.

Comment: Somehow I still get Invalid Input with this implementation: https://newbedev.com/deserialising-json-to-derived-types-in-asp-net-web-api. It looks like the endpoint still doesn't accept the derived type. Any advice?

Answer (score 5):

You can take leverage of the Factory pattern that will return the tags you want to create based on the JSON input. Create a factory, call it TagsFactory, that implements the following interface:

```
public interface ITagsFactory
{
    string CreateTags(int dataType, string jsonInput);
}
```

Create a TagsFactory like below:

```
public class TagsFactory : ITagsFactory
{
    public string CreateTags(int dataType, string jsonInput)
    {
        switch(dataType)
        {
            case 1:
                var intTagsDto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TagForCreateDto1(jsonInput);
                // your logic to create the tags below
                ...
                var tagsModel = GenerateTags();
                return the JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tagsModel);

            case 5:
                var ListTagsDto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TagForCreateDto2>(jsonInput);
                // your logic to create the tags below
                ...
                var tagsModel = GenerateTags();
                return the JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tagsModel);
        }
    }
}
```

For little more separation of concerns, you can move the GenerateTags logic out of the factory to its own class.

> Once the above is in place, I would suggest making a slight change to the design of your
> `TagsController`. Add the following parameters to the `CreateTags` action
>
> - data-type or tag-name. Whatever is easier to handle and read it using `[FromHeader]`
> - jsonInput and read it using `[FromBody]`

Your controller will then look like below, making use of the ITagsFactory injected via DI

```
[Route("api")]
public class TagsController : Controller
{
    private readonly ITagsFactory _tagsFactory;

    public TagsController(ITagsFactory tagsFactory)
    {
        _tagsFactory= tagsFactory;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("tags")]
    public IActionResult CreateTags([FromHeader(Name = "data-type")] string dataType, [FromBody] string jsonInput)
    {
        var tags = _tagsFactory.CreateTags(dataType, jsonInput);
        
        return new ObjectResult(tags)
        {
            StatusCode = 200
        };
    }
}
```

The work is almost done. However, in order to read the raw JSON input from the body, you need to add the `CustomInputFormatter` and register it at the Startup

```
public class RawRequestBodyInputFormatter : InputFormatter
{
    public RawRequestBodyInputFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
    }
    public override bool CanRead(InputFormatterContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body))
        {
            var content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            return await InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(content);
        }
    }
}
```

Register the formatter and the `TagsFactory` in the Startup like below:

```
services.AddSingleton<ITagsFactory, TagsFactory>();
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.InputFormatters.Insert(0, new RawRequestBodyInputFormatter());
}
```

That way your endpoint will remain the same. If you need to add more TagTypes, you just need to add that case to the `TagsFactory`. You can probably think that it's the violation of OCP. However, the Factory needs to know what kind of object it needs to create. If you like to abstract it more, you can make use of AbstractFactory, but I think that would be overkill.